# Scala factorial syntax error

Tags: scala, factorial

I wrote the following code:

```
def factorial(x: Int, factorial( x => { if (x == 0) 1 else x * factorial(x - 1) })): Int = factorial(3)
```

But got the error:

```
<console>:1: error: ':' expected but '(' found.
```

Answer (score 3):

This part of the code makes sense (syntactically, at least):

```
def factorial(...): Int = factorial(3)
```

What goes in the `...` are the function's arguments. You were starting off fine with `x:Int`

```
def factorial(x: Int, ...): Int = factorial(3)
```

But then it kind of goes off the rails syntactically with `factorial(x=>{if(x==0)1 else x*factorial(x-1)})`. I don't really know what to say about that, except that it's definitely not a function argument. That's an *expression*, which is the sort of thing you'd put in the function body (after the `=`), not in an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

You have `factorial` as a param item for your def, that is incorrect. Try:

```
def factorial(x:Int): Int =
  if (x == 0) 1
  else x * factorial(x - 1)
```